# How do I store spring security users in a hibernate database?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have spring security setup with

https://github.com/davidahines/spacechip/tree/spring_security

Right now it looks at the user in the xml file, this is not optimal, I want to look in my database for the user. How do I do that?

Here is my security.xml file:

https://github.com/davidahines/spacechip/blob/spring_security/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml

I think maybe what I need to do is make a hibernate bean for users? Do I need to make one for roles as well? How do I tell it to look at my hibernate connection instead of the xml file?

I am basically looking to do something like this:

http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-using-db.jsp

But with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Followed this guide:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/

What I needed was to create a UserDetailsService implementation.